# Excel flash autofill row based on column

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

So i'm trying to auto-fill a row based on a column value. The row needs to be filled based on a column value X which was used in previous rows. So for example if I have columns ID, Contact and Company and filled the company cell out it would automatically look for a row that matches that company value and auto-fill the rest of the row. I've tried using some of the autofill functions and I tried a Vlookup sub for VBA but I have been unable to get the result I want.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that ID is column A, Contact is Column B and Company is Column C, and the current row is row 10. Put the following formula in B10:

```
=VLOOKUP(A10;A$1:C9;2;FALSE)
```

And in C10:

```
=VLOOKUP(A10;A$1:C9;3;FALSE)
```

Now, as soon as you add an ID to column A, then column B and C are automatically populated. You can copy the formula for columns B and C to later rows.

If you don't want `#N/A` to appear in cells before an ID is entered, you can use formulae like this in B10 and C10:

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A10;A$1:C9;2;FALSE));"";(VLOOKUP(A10;A$1:C9;2;FALSE)))
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A10;A$1:C9;3;FALSE));"";(VLOOKUP(A10;A$1:C9;3;FALSE)))
```

If you are on another row, replace any 10s in the formula with the current row number, and any 9s with the row number - 1.

Comment: Ah ok I see the logic behind this i think. We look up the ID from A1-A9 and then if its found populate row 10 with values.Unfortunately with the syntax you've used I get an error with the formula. Also can the lookup work if the columns were to the left of ID? So if the ID was in column D for example and autofill backwards

Comment: What error are you getting? I did spot a mistake or two and made an edit; are you perhaps using an older version? I think looking up data to the left of a column is harder, though not impossible, using functions like INDEX and MATCH. See for example https://excel.tips.net/T007001_Using_VLOOKUP_to_Access_Information_to_the_Left.html

Comment: It could be that your language settings are different to mine, in which case you need commas in your formulae instead of semicolons.

Comment: Yeah it was the comma issue, ill try and do more of it when I get home. Getting this right will save me hours

Comment: Excellent I seem to understand this now and how the column references work. If i wanted these formulas to be relative to the rows do i just need to copy the formulas?

Comment: Yes, you can just click on a cell, copy, and then paste into another cell (or drag the cell border down from the square at the bottom right). All the row references should update automatically. In Excel, if you don't put a `$` in front of a row or column reference, it updates it when you copy and paste the formula